# SQL Server create a view from multiple tables with indirect referencing

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have four tables:

```
CUSTOMER(CustomerId, CustomerName)
SITE(SiteId, SiteName, CustomerId(FK ref CUSTOMER))
TOOL(ToolId, ToolName, SiteId(FK ref SITE))
TICKET(TicketId, Amount, ToolId(FK ref TOOL))
```

Key points:

- One customer can have multiple sites
- One tool belongs to only one customer, and will reside in only one site that belongs to that customer

I want to create a view that looks like this:

```
VIEW_TICKETS(TicketId, Amount, CustomerName, SiteName, ToolName)
```

I understand that I can get the `ToolName`, for instance, by doing something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW ViewTicket
AS
SELECT TICKET.TicketId, TICKET.Amount, TOOL.ToolName
FROM
TICKET, TOOL
WHERE
TICKET.ToolId = TOOL.ToolId
```

But since in the `TICKET` table I don't have a direct reference to either `Customer` or `Site` tables, how can I get `SiteName` and `CustomerName` as well?

Comment: EVOLVE. Just don't use [old style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to join the other tables as well.

```
CREATE VIEW viewticket
AS
SELECT ti.ticketid,
       ti.amount,
       cu.customername,
       si.sitename,
       tl.toolname
       FROM ticket ti
            LEFT JOIN tool tl
                      ON tl.toolid = ti.toolid
            LEFT JOIN site si
                      ON si.siteid = tl.siteid
            LEFT JOIN customer cu
                      ON cu.customerid = si.customerid;
```

`LEFT JOIN`s seem more appropriate though (unless all the foreign keys are declared `NOT NULL`).

And consider never using a `,` join ever again. Always use the proper syntax with the `JOIN` keyword and an `ON` clause (unless it's a `CROSS JOIN`). That's easier to read and understand, clearer and less error prone.